# How to import datetime with miliseconds in snowflake table

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-schema

I created csv files and uploaded these file to AWS S3 bucket.
In csv file I took timestamp column and data in Timespan Column is like :

'2006-10-01 18:26:47.523'

whenever I tried to import this value to snowflake, able record get inserted as

10 OCT 2014 18:2647 700, any body can guide me so I can import the data with miliseconds column.

Thanks shri